# How to change the class of certain element without creating a new one?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, calendar

I am currently working on a calendar. 
When users add an event on a certain date, the date on the calendar will get another background color by changing the class it belongs.

This is I've tried so far:

```
for ( $day = 1; $day <= $day_count; $day++, $str++) {
    $date = $ym . '-' . $day;
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
        if($date == $event_data[$i]['event_date'] && $date!=$today){
          $week .= "<td class='event'><a href = 'add_calendar.php?date=".$date."'>".$day."</a></td>";
        }
    }
    if ($today == $date ) {
        $date_replaced = str_replace(":","",date('Y:m:d'));
        $week .= "<td class='today'><a href = 'add_calendar.php?date=".$date."'>".$day."</a>";
    }
    else {
        $week .= "<td><a href = 'add_calendar.php?date=".$date."'>".$day."</a>";
    } 
     $week .= '</td>';  
    if ($str % 7 == 6 || $day == $day_count) {
        if ($day == $day_count) {
            $week .= str_repeat('<td></td>', 6 - ($str % 7));
        }
        $weeks[] = '<tr>' . $week . '</tr>';
        $week = '';
    }
}
```

Yet, it turned to be like what the picture shows: 
when there is an event added, then there is a new date showing and mess up the calendar. 
[image: The calendar]

Any knows how to fix that? So many thanks!

The css for the calendar is:

```
    .today {
        background: orange;
    }
    .event {
        background: #f6ffdb;
    }
```

Comment: What is `$len`?

Comment: Whatever `$len` contains, it adds a new `<td>` with the class `event` multiple times. Are you sure you want to add new `td` and not only change the output within that `td`?

Comment: @Jeto It's a variable that counts how many event that has been fetched from database.

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, that's the problem. But I don't know how to **only** change the class instead of adding a new one.

Comment: @Lykas well then for each event that has been added you add a "day" entry into your week's row. Isn't that the issue?

Comment: @Jeto Yes, but is there any way to change the class not to add a new one?

Comment: @Lykas You just want to test `is there an event that day (which is not today)` and then you add the one `<td class="event">` (once). Else you check if it's today. Etc.

Comment: @Jeto Yes, but I don't know where I can add the class.

Comment: @Lykas The class is added by echoing a td with the `event` class...? Anyway, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You must check if an day is already rendred

Try this

```
for ( $day = 1; $day <= $day_count; $day++, $str++) {
$datesRendred = array();
$date = $ym . '-' . $day;
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
    if($date == $event_data[$i]['event_date'] && $date!=$today && !in_array($date, $datesRendred)){
        $week .= "<td class='event'><a href = 'add_calendar.php?date=".$date."'>".$day."</a></td>";
        $datesRendred[]  = $date;
    }
}
if (!in_array($date, $datesRendred)) {
    if ($today == $date) {
        $date_replaced = str_replace(":","",date('Y:m:d'));
        $week .= "<td class='today'><a href = 'add_calendar.php?date=".$date."'>".$day."</a>";
        $datesRendred[]  = $date;
        $week .= '</td>';  
    }
    else {
        $week .= "<td><a href = 'add_calendar.php?date=".$date."'>".$day."</a>";
         $week .= '</td>';  
         $datesRendred[]  = $date;
    }

}

    if ($str % 7 == 6 || $day == $day_count) {
        if ($day == $day_count) {
            $week .= str_repeat('<td></td>', 6 - ($str % 7));
        }
        $weeks[] = '<tr>' . $week . '</tr>';
        $week = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems so reasonable, but still doesn't work. There is always a new date created when there is an event. ;(

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, no need for a loop. Something like this should work (but obviously it's hard to test it on my own, so you might still need a couple adjustments).

```
<?php
for ($day = 1; $day <= $day_count; $day++, $str++) {
    $date = $ym . '-' . $day;
    if ($date == $event_data[$i]['event_date'] && $date != $today) {
        $week .= "<td class='event'><a href = 'add_calendar.php?date=" . $date . "'>" . $day . "</a></td>";
    }
    elseif ($today == $date) {
        $date_replaced = str_replace(":", "", date('Y:m:d'));
        $week .= "<td class='today'><a href = 'add_calendar.php?date=" . $date . "'>" . $day . "</a>";
    }
    else {
        $week .= "<td><a href = 'add_calendar.php?date=" . $date . "'>" . $day . "</a>";
    }
    $week .= '</td>';
    if ($str % 7 == 6 || $day == $day_count) {
        if ($day == $day_count) {
            $week .= str_repeat('<td></td>', 6 - ($str % 7));
        }
        $weeks[] = '<tr>' . $week . '</tr>';
        $week = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: The second loop in the question is for running this statement, since there might be more than one event fetched from database. 
` for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
        if($date == $event_data[$i]['event_date'] && $date!=$today){
          $week .= "<td class='event'><a href = 'add_calendar.php?date=".$date."'>".$day."</a></td>";
           
        }
    } `
If there is no loop here, it won't work well actually.

Comment: What do you want to display if there are several events? Whether there is one or multiple of them, you still want to display only one "day" entry with the `event`class, right? Cause right now, you're displaying several, which is your actual issue.